# Making input and submit display exactly inline

Tags: html, css

I have spent a while encouraging an input form and the submit button to display exactly inline (i.e. same height and vertical position) in both Firefox and Safari. But I'm not having much luck; can anyone help?

The current CSS for the 'Keep in touch' widget on this page: [www.landedhouses.co.uk](http://www.landedhouses.co.uk) is:

```
form.mc4wp-form p{margin-left:0px !important; display:inline; }
form.mc4wp-form input {width:135px; padding:7px;}
form.mc4wp-form input[type=submit] {width:54px; margin-left:5px;}
```

But the submit button is still a pixel out. I think the CSS elsewhere is overriding something... any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have done some changes in your css try it if it works for you.

```
#right input[type="submit"] {
    clear: both;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
}

form.mc4wp-form input[type="submit"] {
    margin-left: 19px;
    width: 54px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it just causes the 'Submit' button to drop a line... argh.